# how auto save photo from camera without asking user (easily way)

Tags: android, camera, photos, autosave

---

Hi
I'm looking for a way to save photos from the camera device directly without ask the user to save or not. I'm not implementing the Camera classes or overriding it. I'm simply using this code above. Do you have any ideas on how to do it?

```
TextReader tr = new TextReader(TextReader.DIRECTORY_EMPRESAS);
String path = TextReader.PARENT_PATH + "/" + TextReader.DIRECTORY_IMAGES;
String dataAtual = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());

if(tr.verificaDiretorios(path)){
    String pictureName = dataAtual + DADOS.get(0) + ".jpg";
    File pathEmpresa = new File(path + "/" + TextReader.FILE_NAME);
    File imageFile;

    if(pathEmpresa.exists()){
         imageFile = new File(pathEmpresa, pictureName);        
         Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
         //startActivity(i);
         startActivityForResult(i, 2);

    }else{
        if(pathEmpresa.mkdir()){        
            imageFile = new File(pathEmpresa, pictureName);     
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
            //startActivity(i);
            startActivityForResult(i, 2);
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("Não foi possivel criar o diretorio: " +         pathEmpresa);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with an `Intent`. You need to use the `Camera` class.

Refer to the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

---

Quick Example:

```
Camera camera = camera.open();
camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        if (data != null) {
            Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data);
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mydir");
            f.mkdirs();//Grab file directory
            f = new File(f, "mypicturefilename"); //Grab picture file location
            BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
            picture.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, os);//Write image to file
            picture.recycle(); //Clean up
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Zed Scio. Do you know which methods to override from         Camera class should I implement to save it directly?

Comment: I'll do some customize in my software later on tests, then I'll use your example. Thanks